# Crystal Reports, Cross tab

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5, crystal-reports-9

I am not getting correct results on Google as I am not able to put correct keywords for my query. Same applies for Stackoverflow too. So I am putting in my question.

In report footer of crystal reports, I am using cross tab. I am expecting output as shown below,

```
             | Count of units    |      Rent
-------------|-------------------|----------------------------------------------
Unit Type A  |      10           |     sum of rent of all units under unit type A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unit Type B  |      20           |     sum of rent of all units under unit type B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So far I was able to achieve as shown below but that is not helping,

```
             |Count of units       |   Rent
----------------------------------------------------------
Unit Type A  |      10             |  sum of rent of UT A
             | sum of rent of UT A |  10
----------------------------------------------------------
Unit Type B  |      20             |  sum of rent of UT B
             | sum of rent of UT B |  20
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am expecting through cross-tab? If not, any other solutions? 
Thanks in advance for all your Help!

Comment: Not sure why the question is down voted? A reason would help me in improving my question.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  It's not clear from your question what is not working.

Comment: I am trying to get an output as shown in my first diagram. I am trying to get unit type wise summary of count of units and sum of total rent. I don't think there is need to understand what is unit type or units but still I will add few more points to help you understand. My report brings data whose detail rows have unit type column. My unit types are not fixed, they change based on filter conditions. I am trying to get a cross tab summary of unit types which will give me unit type wise count of unit (e.g. unit type can be 1 BHK or 2BHK) and unit type wise sum of rent. I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes, it is possible to achieve what you are trying to do. The easiest way is to have one row (unit type) and two summarized fields (count of units, sum of rent. No Columns. You will need to customize the label.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried doing what you said but I am not getting count of units and rent in two different columns. It is giving me output as shown in diagram 2 above.